# Access object by reference

Tags: java, object, reference, equals

What will be the output of following program? I am not aware of object assignment or references.

```
class ObjEx
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        ObjEx ob=new ObjEx();
        Object o = ob;

    if(o==ob)
        System.out.println("1");
    if(o!=ob)
        System.out.println("10");
    if(o.equals(ob))
        System.out.println("101");
    if(ob.equals(o))
        System.out.println("1101");

    }
}
```

Options: A)1    (B)10    (C)101     (D)1101
Please explain me that what will be output and how is it possible? 
I am getting output on my screen as but I am not getting this program:

1

101

1101

Comment: If only there was a way to run the program and find out...

Comment: You answered your own question, good sir. `o==ob`, `o.equals(ob)`, and `ob.equals(o)'; all of these things are true! `o==ob` most of all; there is only one `ObjEx` instance and there are two references to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `if(o==ob)` you are comparing references 
and for the last 2 cases:

```
if(o.equals(ob))
if(ob.equals(o))
```

In java equals is an operation to compare the objects and this operation is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, **x.equals(y)** should return true if and only if **y.equals(x)** returns true.